# How to only allow certain characters in python types?

Tags: python, python-typing, strong-typing, python-3.9

How can I do something like this in python?

```
type something = "a" | "b"
const anotherthing: something = "c" // gives error
```

This typescript code does not allows to set the value of `anotherthing` to anything other than `a` or `b` and If I try to use any other values it gives an error in the ide.

How can I use sort of like this in python?

I have tried the following python code.

```
from typing import Union

something = Union["a", "b"]
anotherthing: something = "c" # it does not give any error
```

I am using pycharm as my ide.

Comment: Python variables have no fixed type.

Comment: @Sid I know python is dynamically typed but isn't there any way to do it like this using the typings provided by python.